# Why an exception is thrown when removing an item via iterator while running over the list?

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, iterator

I invetigate the code of *remove* method of class *ListIterator* and i can't understand why after removing an item while running over the list, an exception is thrown when trying to get the next element after the remove.
Here is the source I have read:

```
   public void remove() {

                if (lastRet < 0)


                    throw new IllegalStateException();


                checkForComodification();

                try {
                    SubList.this.remove(lastRet);

                    cursor = lastRet;
                    lastRet = -1;
                    expectedModCount = ArrayList.this.modCount;


                } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {


                    throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
                }
            }
```

The things I can't understand:

1. Why *remove* method gets *lastRet* and not *cursor*. We want to remove current item and not the one we have already passed on?

2.Why *lastRet* is set to -1?

3.The following line:  *expectedModCount = ArrayList.this.modCount;*
set *expectedModCount * to be equal to *modCount*, so in next iteration when both variable will be checked for equality, the if will "say" true and everything ok.
I read a lot of article over the net, and some answers in SO, but still can't understand

Since I have got response that says the code isn't cause a run time exception,  here is the code which caused it:

```
    public class Testing
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List <String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("a");
        list.add("b");
        list.add("c");
        list.add("d");
        list.add("e");

        Iterator<String> iterator = list.listIterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext())
        {
            String st = iterator.next();
            if (st.equals("c"))
            {
                list.remove(index);
            }

            else
            {
                System.out.println(st);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: I never got an exception from an Iterator after calling that Iterator’s `remove` method.  Consider editing your question and including a [mre] that demonstrates how Iterator.next throws an exception after Iterator.remove has been called.

Comment: @VGR, I have added a code that cause a run time exception

Comment: You are not calling the remove method of Iterator.  You are calling the remove method of List.  Altering a Collection while iterating over it is documented as being likely to cause a ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: @VGR, I understand! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The javadoc for Iterator.remove() says:

```
Removes from the underlying collection the last element returned by this iterator
```

So the cursor is pointing to the next element by the time this method is called, hence lastRet is used.

2. -1 means not found. It's set to -1 because you just removed lastRet hence it doesn't exist any more. This means you can't call remove() again without calling next() first: if you look at next(), it will update lastRet
3. Calling ArrayList.this.remove() changes the modCount (modCount is managed by AbstractList, a superclass of the ArrayList iterator that you are looking at). Since this change is caused by the method itself, we know that this is a valid change (in other words, we just requested to change the list). So the local variable (expectedModCount) is updated.
   If this list is modified by another instance of the iterator, then AbstractList's modCount will change, but expectedModCount, which belongs to the current instance won't. This way the current instance will know that there has been a concurrent modification.

---

Extra question:

I understand. just small question please.. If I have two different thread that are running with for/while loop on the same list (not with an Iterator). And one of them removing an item, in this case exception won't occur? Only when using Iterators system is "safe"?

Multi-threading is not a 'small' question :)

The short answer is that no, it's not safe in either case. Whatever loop you use, as 1 thread is checking if it's safe to do another loop (whether it is .hasNext(), or i < size()), another thread could be at the same time removing/adding elements. So while you won't get a concurrent modification exception if you are using a for loop, you may get an index out of bounds exception.

You should try yourself. Here are some hacky examples (I am using LinkedList for quick removal operations, since using an iterator to remove objects from the beginning of the list is very slow)

Iterator (throws ConcurrentModificationException):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        List<Long> list = new LinkedList<>();
        for (long i1 = 0; i1 < 1_000_000; i1++) {
            list.add(i1);
        }

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        List<Callable<Integer>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
        Iterator<Long> iterator = list.iterator();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            tasks.add(() -> {
                int count = 0;
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    iterator.next();
                    iterator.remove();
                    count++;
                }
                System.out.println("Thread " + Thread.currentThread() + " removed " + count + " items");
                return count;
            });
        }
        List<Future<Integer>> results = executorService.invokeAll(tasks);
        int sum = 0;
        for (Future<Integer> result : results) {
            sum += result.get();
        }
        System.out.println("sum of removed items = " + sum);
        executorService.shutdown();
    }

}
```

Replacing with a for i loop (throws IndexOutOfBoundsException):

```
        List<Long> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (long i1 = 0; i1 < 1_000_000; i1++) {
            list.add(i1);
        }

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        List<Callable<Integer>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            tasks.add(() -> {
                int count = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
                    list.remove(list.size() - 1);
                    count++;
                }
                System.out.println("Thread " + Thread.currentThread() + " removed " + count + " items");
                return count;
            });
        }
        List<Future<Integer>> results = executorService.invokeAll(tasks);
        int sum = 0;
        for (Future<Integer> result : results) {
            sum += result.get();
        }
        System.out.println("sum of removed items = " + sum);
        executorService.shutdown();
```

One thing you can do to avoid these exceptions is to use a **synchronized** block, which makes sure only 1 thread is allowed to execute inside at a time - it is necessary to check again after entering the synchronized block whether the condition is still true:

```
        List<Long> list = new LinkedList<>();
        for (long i1 = 0; i1 < 1_000_000; i1++) {
            list.add(i1);
        }

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        List<Callable<Integer>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
        Iterator<Long> iterator = list.iterator();
        Object lock = new Object();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            tasks.add(() -> {
                int count = 0;
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    synchronized (lock) {
                        if (iterator.hasNext()) {
                            iterator.next();
                            iterator.remove();
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Thread " + Thread.currentThread() + " removed " + count + " items");
                return count;
            });
        }
        List<Future<Integer>> results = executorService.invokeAll(tasks);
        int sum = 0;
        for (Future<Integer> result : results) {
            sum += result.get();
        }
        System.out.println("sum of removed items = " + sum);
        executorService.shutdown();
```

Java also has concurrent collections that you can use to enable multiple threads to do parallel computations.

Giving each thread its own iterator requires changing to something like ConcurrentLinkedQueue to avoid concurrent modification exceptions. However, the code gives a very wrong result:

```
        Collection<Long> list = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
        for (long i1 = 0; i1 < 1_000_000; i1++) {
            list.add(i1);
        }

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        List<Callable<Integer>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
        Object lock = new Object();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            tasks.add(() -> {
                int count = 0;
                Iterator<Long> iterator = list.iterator();
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    synchronized (lock) {
                        if (iterator.hasNext()) {
                            iterator.next();
                            iterator.remove();
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Thread " + Thread.currentThread() + " removed " + count + " items");
                return count;
            });
        }
        List<Future<Integer>> results = executorService.invokeAll(tasks);
        int sum = 0;
        for (Future<Integer> result : results) {
            sum += result.get();
        }
        System.out.println("sum of removed items = " + sum);
        executorService.shutdown();
```

Which prints out

```
sum of removed items = 1105846
```

So it seems like iterator is not very thread-safe :)

If we get rid of iterator:

```
        Queue<Long> list = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
        for (long i1 = 0; i1 < 1_000_000; i1++) {
            list.add(i1);
        }

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        List<Callable<Integer>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            tasks.add(() -> {
                int count = 0;
                while (!list.isEmpty()) {
                    list.poll();
                    count++;
                }
                System.out.println("Thread " + Thread.currentThread() + " removed " + count + " items");
                return count;
            });
        }
        List<Future<Integer>> results = executorService.invokeAll(tasks);
        int sum = 0;
        for (Future<Integer> result : results) {
            sum += result.get();
        }
        System.out.println("sum of removed items = " + sum);
        executorService.shutdown();
```

This is better:

```
sum of removed items = 1000007
```

Putting back the lock:

```
        Queue<Long> list = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
        for (long i1 = 0; i1 < 1_000_000; i1++) {
            list.add(i1);
        }

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        List<Callable<Integer>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
        Object lock = new Object();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            tasks.add(() -> {
                int count = 0;
                while (!list.isEmpty()) {
                    synchronized (lock) {
                        if (!list.isEmpty()) {
                            list.poll();
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Thread " + Thread.currentThread() + " removed " + count + " items");
                return count;
            });
        }
        List<Future<Integer>> results = executorService.invokeAll(tasks);
        int sum = 0;
        for (Future<Integer> result : results) {
            sum += result.get();
        }
        System.out.println("sum of removed items = " + sum);
        executorService.shutdown();
```

Seems to work

```
sum of removed items = 1000000
```

Comment: great explanation. According to it, can't understand why my code cause a run time exception (I have added the code to the post)

Comment: You are doing what I mentioned. You call remove on list, which changes modCount for the **list**, while the **iterator**’s expectedModCount is not changed.

Comment: You should call iterator.remove() basically, not list.remove

Comment: I understand. just small question please.. If I have two different thread that are running with for/while loop on the same list (not with an Iterator). And one of them removing an item, in this case exception won't occur? Only when using Iterators system is "safe"?

Comment: I added some more info for you in the answer.

Comment: thanks a lot! I have a problem with my computer. I will run the code you attached and approve your answer until tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: I have read all your example only today. As I can see you always provide to the Threads/Tasks the same *Iterator*. Shouldn't you provide for each Thread/Task a  different *Iterator*?

Comment: Yeah, it's interesting to see what would happen with 10 iterators, I added the result to the answer.